# How to create a regex to find files two folders inside a URL?

Tags: python, regex, regex-lookarounds, regex-group, regex-greedy

When i visit this URL(https://www.example.com/blog/author/) it shows me the articles written by an author. I need to create a script to find all the links on that page of that author's articles. Now the articles are in a different folder, two folders inside the server(https://www.example.com/blog/some-folder/article). 
The folders are of following two types:

https://www.example.com/some-numerical/this-is-a-post/

i.e. https://www.example.com/123/sample-article

https://www.example.com/some-word/this-is-a-post/

i.e. https://www.example.com/data/sample-post/

How do I accomplish this using regex and python?

I have tried the following code but is unable to get the regex right.

```
import re
import requests
r = requests.get("https://www.example.com/blog/author/abc") 
data = r.content  # Content of response
links = re.findall('https://www.example.com/blog/*+/', data)
print(links)
```

this simply prints out A URL: https://www.example.com/blog/

Comment: @GiorgosMyrianthous the desired output is 1.https://www.example.com/blog/123/article-on-cats 2.https://www.example.com/blog/cats/article-on-dogs

Comment: Are you scraping the page; finding the `a` tags; and extracting the `href` attributes?

Comment: @wwii yes i am scrapping the page but i am looking for a particular type of links. www.example.com/123/sample-article or www.example.com/dogs/sample-article

Answer (score 0):

If we wish to pass URLs that have `example.com` and `sample-article`, then we can start with an expression similar to:

```
(https?:\/\/)?(www\.)?example\.com\/(.+)\/(sample-article)
```

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/86TIkM/1)

#### Test

```
# coding=utf8
# the above tag defines encoding for this document and is for Python 2.x compatibility

import re

regex = r"(https?:\/\/)?(www\.)?example\.com\/(.+)\/(sample-article)"

test_str = ("example.com/123/sample-article\n"
    "example.com/dogs/sample-article\n"
    "www.example.com/123/sample-article\n"
    "www.example.com/dogs/sample-article\n"
    "https://www.example.com/dogs/sample-article\n"
    "http://www.example.com/dogs/sample-article")

matches = re.finditer(regex, test_str, re.MULTILINE)

for matchNum, match in enumerate(matches, start=1):

    print ("Match {matchNum} was found at {start}-{end}: {match}".format(matchNum = matchNum, start = match.start(), end = match.end(), match = match.group()))

    for groupNum in range(0, len(match.groups())):
        groupNum = groupNum + 1

        print ("Group {groupNum} found at {start}-{end}: {group}".format(groupNum = groupNum, start = match.start(groupNum), end = match.end(groupNum), group = match.group(groupNum)))

# Note: for Python 2.7 compatibility, use ur"" to prefix the regex and u"" to prefix the test string and substitution.
```

#### RegEx Circuit

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) visualizes regular expressions:

[image]

---

#### Edit:

If we wish to parse HTML here, it would be much better to use HTML parser. Otherwise, modifications of our expression would become tedious and unnecessary.

If that was not an option, we would start with an expression with left and right boundaries similar to:

```
href=\"((https?:\/\/www\.example\.com)\/[a-z]+?\/[0-9]+?\/[a-z-]+\/)\"
```

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/A1BMvW/1)

#### Test

```
# coding=utf8
# the above tag defines encoding for this document and is for Python 2.x compatibility

import re

regex = r"href=\"((https?:\/\/www\.example\.com)\/[a-z]+?\/[0-9]+?\/[a-z-]+\/)\""

test_str = "<div id=\"content\" class=\"\" role=\"main\"><article id=\"post-5463\" class=\"post-entry clearfix post-5463 post type-post status-publish format-standard has-post-thumbnail hentry category-13 tag-wordpress\"><div class=\"post-box\"><div class=\"post-header clearfix\"><div class=\"post-format-icon post-format-standard\"> <i class=\"fa fa-pencil\"></i></div><div class=\"post-info-wrap\"><h2 class=\"post-title\"><a href=\"https://www.getastra.com/blog/911/wordpress-hacked-sending-spam/\" title=\"WordPress Website Hacked &#038; Sending Spam: Symptoms, Causes &#038; Cleanup\" rel=\"bookmark\">WordPress Website Hacked &#038; Sending Spam: Symptoms, Causes &#038; Cleanup</a></h2><div class=\"post-meta clearfix\"><ul><li><img style=\"--aspect-ratio:1;\" alt='' data-src='https://secure.gravatar.com/avatar/fc475099fdd637e1ec27d0b5c73cb876?s=35&#038;d=retro&#038;r=g' data-srcset='https://secure.gravatar.com/avatar/fc475099fdd637e1ec27d0b5c73cb876?s=70&#038;d=retro&#038;r=g 2x' class='avatar avatar-35 photo lazyload' height='35' width='35' /></li><li><a href=\"https://www.getastra.com/blog/author/vikas/\" rel=\"author\">By: <span class=\"fn\"></span></a></li><li><i class=\"fa fa-clock-o\"></i><time class=\"entry-date published\" datetime=\"2019-05-09T16:21:26+05:30\">May 9, 2019</time></li><li><i class=\"fa fa-comments\"></i><a href=\"/#respond\" class=\"comments-link\">Leave a comment</a></li></ul></div></div></div><div class=\"post-media\"> <figure class=\"post-thumbnail-wrapper \"> <a href=\"https://www.getastra.com/blog/911/wordpress-hacked-sending-spam/\" title=\"WordPress Website Hacked &#038; Sending Spam: Symptoms, Causes &#038; Cleanup\" rel=\"bookmark\"> <img width=\"748\" height=\"350\" data-srcset=\"https://www.getastra.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2019/05/CopyofCopyofCopyofTemplate84_4c3eb9ee60c31a6a26529b08360fa628_2000-748x350.png 748w, https://www.getastra.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2019/05/CopyofCopyofCopyofTemplate84_4c3eb9ee60c31a6a26529b08360fa628_2000.png 750w\" data-src=\"https://www.getastra.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2019/05/CopyofCopyofCopyofTemplate84_4c3eb9ee60c31a6a26529b08360fa628_2000-748x350.png\" class=\"attachment-blog-featured size-blog-featured wp-post-image lazyload\" alt=\"WordPress Website Hacked &amp; Sending Spam: Symptoms, Causes &amp; Cleanup\" sizes=\"(max-width: 748px) 100vw, 748px\" style=\"--aspect-ratio:2.1371428571429;\" /><div class=\"thumb-overlay\"> <i class=\"fa fa-link\"></i></div> </a> </figure></div><div class=\"post-con</a></li></ul></div></body></html>"

matches = re.finditer(regex, test_str, re.MULTILINE | re.IGNORECASE)

for matchNum, match in enumerate(matches, start=1):

    print ("Match {matchNum} was found at {start}-{end}: {match}".format(matchNum = matchNum, start = match.start(), end = match.end(), match = match.group()))

    for groupNum in range(0, len(match.groups())):
        groupNum = groupNum + 1

        print ("Group {groupNum} found at {start}-{end}: {group}".format(groupNum = groupNum, start = match.start(groupNum), end = match.end(groupNum), group = match.group(groupNum)))

# Note: for Python 2.7 compatibility, use ur"" to prefix the regex and u"" to prefix the test string and substitution.
```

#### Output

```
Match 1 was found at 395-466: href="https://www.getastra.com/blog/911/wordpress-hacked-sending-spam/"
Group 1 found at 401-465: https://www.example.com/blog/911/wordpress-hacked-sending-spam/
Group 2 found at 401-425: https://www.getastra.com
Match 2 was found at 1522-1593: href="https://www.example.com/blog/911/wordpress-hacked-sending-spam/"
Group 1 found at 1528-1592: https://www.example.com/blog/911/wordpress-hacked-sending-spam/
Group 2 found at 1528-1552: https://www.example.com
Match 3 was found at 3065-3136: href="https://www.example.com/blog/911/wordpress-hacked-sending-spam/"
Group 1 found at 3071-3135: https://www.example.com/blog/911/wordpress-hacked-sending-spam/
Group 2 found at 3071-3095: https://www.example.com
```

Comment: you got it a bit wrong. There are 3 slashes before sample article. i.e. www.example.com/blog/dogs/sample-article or www.example.com/blog/123/sample-article. "www.example.com/blog/" this part is constant.

Comment: it didnt work because the sample-article is also a variable, It may change as per article it could be sample-article-1 dogs-are-fun check-this-spam etc. P.S. The article names may have numbers, alphabets and the hyphen "-" sign

Comment: check this out for my real life problem : https://pastebin.com/8VJvNGn9

Comment: here: https://regex101.com/r/86TIkM/5  P.S. Thanks for the efforts though!

Comment: ya sure it matches here but when i run the code it outputs a lot of rubbish.My code can be found here: https://pastebin.com/4QB0ZCMV

Comment: thanks for the efforts. I will try other ways using beautiful soup.This method doesn't seem to be working